# How to get the class labels and predicted probabiltiies for each class for top 5 classes in multiclass classification?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a dictionary with key, value pairs where the values are lists of values as shown below, to add more to the question i have my predicted class probabilities and the corresponding classes which i have made into a dictionary and i want to get the highest 5 probs for each class:

`# gets a dictionary of {'class_name': probability}`

`prob_per_class_dictionary = dict(zip(loaded_model.classes_, probs))`

The dictionary looks like this:

`{0: array([9.65109812e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`1: array([9.30082941e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`2: array([9.42541599e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`3: array([9.54675878e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`4: array([9.00161937e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`5: array([9.33723827e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

`6: array([9.6553016e-07, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00]),`

`7: array([9.45838933e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),`

I want to sort the dictionary such that for each key say 0: array([top 5 values sorted in descending order]). I have tried the following which sorts it in ascending order but i want only the top 5 values in descending order.

```
for key, v_list in prob_per_class_dictionary.items():
    v_list = v_list.sort()`
```

Please let me know what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

i would want my results to look something like this

sorted( zip( loaded_model.classes_, probs[0] ), key=lambda x:x[1] )[-n:]
such that for each class i get the corresponding probs and i get it for top 5 classes and their respective probs.

```
       `[(1019, 0.02498873845258007),`

        `(1421, 0.3491224577864634),`

        `(1295, 0.5342553538931459)]`
```

Comment: So sort it in reverse and take the "top" 5.

Comment: Hi Scott, the reverse sort doesn't work and so this question. The reverse sort gives an error TypeError: 'reverse' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Show how you tried to use it.

Comment: for key, v_list in prob_per_class_dictionary.items():
        v_list = v_list.sort(reverse =True)

Answer (score -1):

Not the most efficient solution, but it'll get it done:

```
v_list.sort()
v_list = v_list.take((-1,-2,-3,-4,-5))
```

Comment: this doesn't give me back the classes like the dict i had

Comment: In what way(s)?  Remember that dicts are unsorted.

Comment: def sort_dict_values(dict):
    for key, v_list in prob_per_class_dictionary.items():
        v_list.sort()
        v_list = v_list.take((-1,-2,-3,-4,-5))
    return key,v_list   how do i get it to sort the entire dict this way?